# how to print json decode api data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want to print data which is coming from api when i print data it print only one data at a time how to print all these data in foreach loop i am using this but not work and getting and error `Trying to get property 'Name' of non-object` how to solve this problems thanks in advance

this is the response

[image]

[image]
this is my code

```
$response = sabreApiCall($url, $data_array);
$results = json_decode($response);

$i =0;
foreach ($results->GeoSearchRS->GeoSearchResults->GeoSearchResult[$i] as $hotel) 
        {

            echo $hotel->Name;
           $i ++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php and compare it with your attempt. Aswell you might want to read about the second parameter of `json_decode` http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php - its way handier in PHP to work with arrays, than with stdClass objects. Additional advice: never use `echo` in development, its awful and hides very useful information from you, use `var_dump()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just return $results as laravel will return it as json.

Comment: above response is the json $results when i print it print_r($results) above response shown

Answer (score 0):

why are you using $i variable to loop through this array. Simply use foreach like this

```
$response = sabreApiCall($url, $data_array);
$results = json_decode($response);


foreach ($results->GeoSearchRS->GeoSearchResults->GeoSearchResult as $hotel) 
        {

            echo $hotel->Name;
        }
    }
```